# Internal 500 error in WCf service get response method

Tags: wcf, getresponse, internal-server-error

Below is my request i get a 500 internal server error at getresponse

```
string requestData = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Header><h:HeaderItem xmlns:h=\"http://tempuri.org/\">a header item</h:HeaderItem><ActivityId CorrelationId=\"090c553b-bfcc-4e4f-94cd-1b4333fe82a9\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics\">377a454b-b543-4c6f-b4ac-3981029b60e6</ActivityId></s:Header><s:Body><string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">a body item</string></s:Body></s:Envelope>";
byte[] requestDataBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/WebService/");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
                request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IWebService/GetMessage");
                request.ContentLength = requestDataBytes.Length;

                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
                streamWriter.Write(requestData);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string responseBody = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Wyh aren't you using a normal WCF proxy client?? Why do it the hard way, if you could use a much nicer and easier way to call your service??

Comment: that is what the requirement is we have to pass soap messages back and forth

Answer (score 1):

I may have an answer for you.

Move the line where you set your headers to the point *before* you set the content type, and retry your code, as follows:

```
       request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/IWebService/GetMessage");
       request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
```

I make this suggestion based on the documentation for the ContentType property for the WebRequest object from MS:

[MS docs on WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contenttype.aspx)

> The value for this property is stored in WebHeaderCollection . If
>   WebHeaderCollection is set, the property value is lost.

Now, I realize we're *not* expressly setting the WebHeaderCollection, but you are setting *a* header *in* that collection, and it made me suspect at least the possibility of this being a problem - rendering your existing ContentType blank, and being interpreted as some default on the inbound side of the web service.

Maybe a long shot, but it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable WCF trace logging on your server and see if it indicates an error.  Typically errors that occur during deserialization or in the WCF layers before hitting your app code will write to this log.

For more info on setting up WCF trace logging, [see here](http://mkdot.net/blogs/dejan/archive/2008/10/23/wcf-tracing-and-message-logging.aspx) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Comment: tx, i did it and the issue in trace file is '<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was sent to a service expecting text/xml; charset=utf-8.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.</Message>'

Comment: What type of binding are you using? basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding? That error message makes it look like maybe your `request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";` is being ignored, but I don't know how it would have been set to "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" instead. The error message looks like a SOAP v2 / wsHttpBinding client trying to talk to a SOAP v1 / basicHttpBinding server.

Comment: I am using basic httpBinding at both places  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWebService" bind at client

Comment: I tried to create http://csharping.com/wcf/building-a-soap-response-envelope-manually-with-the-message-class/  but are facing many issue as i am not awrae about binding is there any sample like this available, can anyone please help me to find out the same thing thanks in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really know what would be wrong with it. I have working code that looks just like yours that uses `WebRequest` to post soap data to a `basicHttpBinding` WCF service, and it works fine. Sorry, but I don't know what else would be wrong.

Comment: Can  you please send me a sample please please just with one function please i badly need it

Comment: I went and looked at my sample code and actually I am using that against a web service that has a custom message inspector that implements a 'pox' (plain old XML) message structure, not SOAP. However it is almost line-for-line identical to your original post, the only diff being I dont set a "SOAPAction" in the header since my web service isnt using soap, and my message content string is ifferent. Otherwise, it is exactly what you listed.  Your error message with "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" is confusing. I dont see how that gets sent, unless you used a different client than shown.

Comment: Can you please give me any idea to help find a sample like this , i am unable to find , u have a better knowledge about this